# How distribution nomenclature is done?

Tags: release-management

How does Ubuntu distribution nomenclature is done? For example why does 14.04 Ubuntu is given the name "Trusty Thar"? Likewise what are the motivation for such nomenclatures for all the released versions? Also who is the authority to decide a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **So, what's with the "Funky Fairy" naming system? Many sensible people have wondered why we chose this naming scheme.**
>
> It came about as a joke on a ferry between Circular Quay and somewhere else, in Sydney, Australia:
>
> lifeless: how long before we make a first release?
> sabdfl: it would need to be punchy. six months max.
> lifeless: six months! thats not a lot of time for polish.
> sabdfl: so we'll have to nickname it the warty warthog release.
>
> [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#History).

That's how the first major Ubuntu release got his name : **Warty Warthog** ... and since then, the form "**Adjective Animal**" stayed.

---

Canonical, in particular Mark Shuttleworth, decides about the release name finally.
But users can propose a name [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames#Code_Name_Suggestions) - it might be picked up by the team eventually.